# Change URL for a module

Tags: magento-1.7, url

I would like to change the name a plugin in order to have a translated to my language URL

www.example.com/newname instead of www.example.com/oldname

Is there any tutorial to find how to do this? Do I have to change the folder name in app and skin, besides the xml files and the IndexController.php?

Am I missing something?

Comment: just need to change store code...

Comment: just need to change store code...

Comment: Can I assume you are trying to translate some module's front name according to language ?

Comment: yes, to access through a translated URL @Prateek

Comment: You can surely achieve that from within the admin. Use URL Rewrite Management feature with redirect set to No for all the custom rewrites.

Comment: Great @Prateek, I solve it with the URL rewrite as you said, thousand thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the modules `config.xml`. You will find a route definition in this form:

```
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <themodule>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>The_Module</module>
                <frontName>oldname</frontName>
            </args>
        </themodule>
    </routers>
</frontend>
```

If the module was developed using Magento coding standards, it does not contain any hard coded URLs, but uses something like `Mage::getUrl('themodule/index')` to build URLs.

Good news is, that the internal route name (`themodule`) is independent from the front name (`oldname`), i.e. the first part of the actual URL.

So you can change

```
<frontname>oldname</frontname>
```

to

```
<frontname>newname</frontname>
```

and all URLs of the module should be changed.

Of course you don't want to modify third party code, so instead of editing this config.xml, you should create your own module, that `depends` on the original module and overrides the front name in its own config.xml:

```
<config>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <themodule>
                <args>
                    <frontName>newname</frontName>
                </args>
            </themodule>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```